# MPI_Scatter segmentation fault dependent on node number

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, mpi

I get a strange behavior when running a test code for MPI_Scatter. The program seems to work fine, but it returns a segmentation fault if the number of nodes is larger than 4. I compile with mpicxx and run with mpirun -n N ./a.o.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

using std::vector;

int main(void){
    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
    int num_PE;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_PE);
    int my_PE;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_PE);

    int data_per_PE=2;
    int remainder=0; //conceptually should be less than data_per_PE but shouldn't matter from code perspective
    vector<int> elem_count(num_PE,data_per_PE); //number of elements to scatter
    elem_count[num_PE-1]=data_per_PE+remainder; //let last PE take extra load
    vector<int> start_send(num_PE); //the offset to send from main buffer
    vector<double> small_vec(data_per_PE+remainder); //small place to store values
    vector<double> bigVec; //the big list to distribute to processes
    if (my_PE==0){
        bigVec.reserve(data_per_PE*num_PE+remainder); //make room
        for(int i=0; i<data_per_PE*num_PE+remainder; i++){
            bigVec.push_back(static_cast<double>(i)+1.0); //1,2,3...
            start_send[i]=i*data_per_PE; //the stride
        }
    }
    // MPI_Scatterv(&bigVec[0],&elem_count[0],&start_send[0],MPI_DOUBLE,&small_vec[0],data_per_PE+remainder,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Scatter(&bigVec[0],data_per_PE,MPI_DOUBLE,&small_vec[0],data_per_PE,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD); //scatter
    if (my_PE==0){
        printf("Proc \t elems \n");
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD); //let everything catch up before printing
    for (int i=0;i<data_per_PE+remainder;i++){
        printf("%d \t %f \n", my_PE, small_vec[i]); //print the values scattered to each processor
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD); //don't think this is necessary but won't hurt
    MPI_Finalize(); //finish

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with the scatter, but rather this line:

```
start_send[i]=i*data_per_PE;
```

Since `i` can go beyond `num_PE`, you write outside of the bounds of `start_send` - overwriting some memory that probably belongs to `small_vec`.

This could have easily been found by creating a truly minimal example.

You have another issue in your code: `&bigVec[0]` is a problem for `my_PE!=0`. While the parameter to `MPI_Scatter` is ignored by non-root ranks, the statement involves dereferencing in `std::vector::operator[]` the first element. As the vector is empty, this is undefined behavior on it's own. [Here is an explanation](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html) as to why that can create subtle problems. Use `bigVec.data()` instead.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, just assumed it was MPI related as it changed with nodes.

Thanks for info on the bigVec dereferencing. I wasn't quite sure how much the non-roots ignored of the scattering function, but glad to know that .data() will be safe.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing past the end of `start_send`'s internal storage, thus corrupting the heap and any other objects contained in it:

```
if (my_PE==0){
    bigVec.reserve(data_per_PE*num_PE+remainder); //make room
    for(int i=0; i<data_per_PE*num_PE+remainder; i++){
        bigVec.push_back(static_cast<double>(i)+1.0); //1,2,3...
        start_send[i]=i*data_per_PE; //the stride               <--- HERE
    }
}
```

`i` runs until `data_per_PE*num_PE+remainder - 1`, but `start_send` has storage for `num_PE` elements only. Writing past the end corrupts the linked list of heap objects and the program likely segfaults when a destructor tries to free a corrupted heap block or when some other heap object is accessed.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Strange that it didn't segfault on lower numbers of nodes.

Comment: Not really that strange. With lower number of nodes less data gets overwritten and it could be that the heap blocks are of some minimal size or the block headers are aligned, so the damage is not visible.